# iOS front camera only app

Tags: ios, camera, plist, requirements

I've had apps denied in the past for not specifying in the plist or something that the app will ONLY run properly on devices with 3g or devices with a compass, or with texting, etc. How do I specify that my app will ONLY run properly with devices that have a front camera (like Skype would have had to do) Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you have to specify it, just test if the camera's available with `picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;`

Comment: I have to if it's a huge part of the app; Apple denies it.. I only don't have to specify if it's a minor feature that isn't a necessity for the app. Thanks though— I will keep your code in mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your app to be used only on devices that have a front camera, then you can specify that by adding `front-facing-camera` to the app [required capabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW4).

However, if the app has enough functionality when running on devices with no front facing camera, then it is probably better not to specify this capability. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3):

> You should include keys only for the features that your application absolutely requires. If your application can accommodate missing features by avoiding the code paths that use those features, do not include the corresponding key.

Comment: Thankyou, wonderful answer! And unfortunately for this app I will need that feature for the app to be really functional... I mean chat would work but video won't.. Thankyou so much for your answer!