# iOS deployment on specific devices only

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I was developing a game targeting iPhone 4/iPad and above....
My question is, can I "somehow" set the deployment target so that it won't be able to run on 3GS or older devices?

All my textures are for HD (iPhone 4 resolution), if it runs on 3GS, all the positions will be wrong and all the images are oversized.

Is there any suggestions on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: u can set 4.0 in deployment so your app only run in 4.0 or latter iOS.

Comment: problem is 3GS still able to run 4.0.... which means it's still able to run my game

Comment: what you have selected in deployment target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Require a front-facing camera from the SDK.  The 3GS will be excluded.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760238/ios-front-camera-only-app) for steps on doing this.